# Array within another array

Tags: php

I have an array like:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [code] => FAC876 )
```

How do I push it into another array using PHP, such that the result is like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [code] => FAC876 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [code] => GEO980 )
      )
```

Comment: I think "I want to" on SO is equivalent to "How do I".

Comment: PLEASE! accept some of your questions

Comment: He never accepted any of the answers to his questions. There should be something in SO that motivates people to accept their answer.

Answer (score 9):

Simply threat the array as any other variable.

So if this is what you got:

```
$array  = array();
$array1 = array( "id"=>1, "code"=>"FAC876" );
$array2 = array( "id"=>2, "code"=>"GEO980" );
```

You could do either

```
$array[] = $array1;
$array[] = $array2;
```

or

```
$array[0] = $array1;
$array[1] = $array2;
```

or

```
$array = array($array1, $array2);
```

or

```
array_push($array, $array1);
array_push($array, $array2);
```

Any of those four possibilites will give you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You almost posted the answer yourself:

```
Array (
    0 => Array ( 'id' => 1, 'code' => 'FAC876' ),
    1 => Array ( 'id' => 2, 'code' => 'GEO980' )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr1 = array(
  'id' => 1,
  'code' => 'FAC876',
);
$arr2 = array(
  $arr1,
  array(
    'id' => 2,
    'code' => 'GEO980',
  ),
);
```

or

```
$arr1 = array(
  'id' => 1,
  'code' => 'FAC876',
);
$arr2 = array(
  'id' => 2,
  'code' => 'GEO980',
);
$arr3 = array($arr1, $arr2);
```

or lots of other ways to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ar=array();
$ar[]=array("no"=>10,"name"=>"abc"); 
$ar[]=array("no"=>20,"name"=>"pqr");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrays = array();

$array1 = array("id" => 1, "code" => "ABC");
$array2 = array("id" => 2, "code" => "DEF");

array_push($arrays, $array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array  = array(array( "id"=>1, "code"=>"FAC876" ) , array( "id"=>2, "code"=>"GEO980" ));
```

or

```
$array  = array();
$array[] = array( "id"=>1, "code"=>"FAC876" );
$array[] = array( "id"=>2, "code"=>"GEO980" );
```

or

```
$array  = array();
array_push($array, array( "id"=>1, "code"=>"FAC876" ));
array_push($array, array( "id"=>2, "code"=>"GEO980" ));
```